# Elements in Groovy MarkupTemplateEngine

Tags: groovy

I'm considering doing a project in [Spring MVC](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-view-groovymarkup) (in Java) using [Groovy's MarkupTemplateEngine](http://groovy-lang.org/templating.html#_the_markuptemplateengine) to render the views. I'm new to Groovy.

**Question**: What is *the Groovy Way* to create reusable view elements?

**Examples**: (syntax may vary)

1. Profile picture

   `profilePicture(someuser)` -> `<img src="/users/profilepics/42" alt="John Doe">`
2. FontAwesome

   `fa('foo')` -> `<i class="fa fa-foo"></i>`
3. Portlet (e.g. Bootstrap)

   `portlet(...) { ... }` ->

   ```
   <div class="portlet">
      <div class="portlet-header">Some title</div>
      <div class="portlet-body">Lots of content</div>
   </div>
   ```

I've picked there three examples, because I have a feeling each might have a different answer.

**What I've found so far**:

I know I can *include other templates*. This might be a solution for 3, but would feel like overkill for 1 and 2.

I also know that I can *extend the base class* of the view and introduce new methods. I have seen an example which added FontAwesome support this way. However, I'd like to split project specific (1) from more generic, reusable (2) methods. Also I'd prefer to have them somewhat namespaced (e.g. `Users.profilePicture(...)` and `Bootstrap.portlet(...)`)

I could use classes with *static methods*. Would this cause any problems? I guess I couldn't access the session, right? (E.g. link to profile in 1, but only if someuser != authenticated user.)

I could just add instances of helper classes to the *model*. But the controller should be mostly oblivious about specific helper requirements in the view.

Or am I missing the point completely and the *Groovy Way* would be to explicitly write these elements out?

Comment: I guess you are talking about Grails template, not just groovy. Right?

Comment: I want to use Spring MVC as base framework. Controllers etc. would be written in Java. I've looked at the available template frameworks and liked what was described in the "Groovy Markup" chapter (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-view-groovymarkup) best. It uses MarkupTemplateEngine as described in the Groovy manual. I don't know about Grails. I think its GSP views are similar but not the same. And it uses Groovy as main language (controllers etc.), which I'm *not* looking for.

Comment: Took another look at Grails/GSP. This is exactly the opposite of what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a template engine that *isn't* JSP (or very similar).

Comment: I prefer to avoid root classes with static methods... IHMO better to use binding for templates.

Comment: Would Fragments work? https://groovy-lang.org/templating.html#_fragments